# How to deal with situation where LSTM fails to learn (constantly makes the same incorrect prediction)

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, keras, lstm

I am trying to use LSTM neural networks in order to make a song composer. Basically this is based of a text generator (tries to predict the next character after looking at a sequence of characters) but instead of characters, it tried to predict notes.

Structure of the midi file that serves as the input (Y-axis is the pitch or note value while X-axis is time):
[image]

And this is the predicted note values:
[image]
[image]

I set an epoch of 50, but it seems that the LSTM's loss rate does not decrease, most of the time its loss rate does not improve.

[image]

I suspect this is because there is an overwhelming number of a particular note (in this case, note value 65) which makes the LSTM lazy during training phase and predict 65 each and every time.

I feel like this is a common problem among LSTMs and time-series based learning algorithms. How would I solve a problem like this? If what I mentioned is not the problem, then what is the problem and how do I solve that?

Here is the code I am using to train if you need it:

```
import numpy 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.utils import np_utils

seq_length = 100

read_path = '../matrices/input/world-is-mine/world-is-mine-y-0.npy' 


raw_text = numpy.load(read_path)


# create mapping of unique chars to integers, and a reverse mapping
chars = sorted(list(set(raw_text)))
char_to_int = dict((c,i) for i,c in enumerate(chars))

n_chars = len(raw_text)
n_vocab = len(chars)


# prepare the dataset of input to output pairs encoded as integers
dataX = []
dataY = []

# dataX is the encoding version of the sequence
# dataY is an encoded version of the next prediction
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length, 1):
    seq_in = raw_text[i:i + seq_length]
    seq_out = raw_text[i+seq_length]
    dataX.append([char_to_int[char] for char in seq_in])
    dataY.append(char_to_int[seq_out])


n_patterns = len(dataX)
print "Total Patterns: ", n_patterns

# reshape X to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length,1))

# normalize
X = X/float(n_vocab)

# one hot encode the output variable
y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)

print 'X: ', X.shape
print 'Y: ', y.shape


# define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
#model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(LSTM(256))
#model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

# There is no test dataset. We are modeling the entire training dataset to learn the probability of each character in a sequence.
# We are interested in a generalization of the dataset that minimizes the chosen loss function
# We are seeking a balance between generalization of the dataset and overfitting but short of memorization

# define the check point
filepath="../checkpoints/weights-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

model.fit(X,y, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Comment: You might be over fitting.. what is your sample size?

Comment: As @Minato said, this sounds like over-fitting.

Comment: This is actually **underfitting**, not **over**fitting since his model simply learnt the expected value of the signal, instead of any training data characteristics.

Comment: Have you tried to traing **longer**? How many points you have between 65 and any other value? You are training on sequences of length 100, maybe it is not enough to capture the change in note? Why not train on the whole signal? In general it seems like a bit hard task (as LSTM will probably have to memorize everything, as this is discrete, extremely short signal, without lots of repeatitions/relations

Comment: @lejlot   How much longer? I felt like it wouldn't make much of a difference if I added more epochs because it most of the epochs fail to improve and learn.

I couldn't really improve increase the size beyond 300 because I get some kind of error [ File "model.py", line 57, in <module>
    y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY) ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity]

Comment: @Minato    This is the size of my X input (406, 200, 1) while the Y is (406, 15) where for X, the first column is equal to number of sequence combinations with the second column equal to the length of each sequence it trains on. And I actually suspect underfitting. It would be great progress to me if I can get it to overfit.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience on working with music data. From my experience with text data, this seems like a under-fitted model. Increasing the training dataset with different note value should overcome the underfitting problem. It seems like the training examples are not enough for learning the note variation. For example, for char language model, 1 MB data is too small for training a reasonable LSTM model. Also, try to train with smaller sequence length (let's say with 20) first. Smaller sequence length will be easier to learn than the longer one, with limited training data.